# Showing only hours and minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to display only hours and minutes in a field if I get them separately

```
[SELECT 
    D.numOperador,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) / 60 AS \[Horas\] ,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) % 60 AS \[Minutos\]

    FROM 
    trkOperadores O
    INNER JOIN trfDespacho D ON O.NumOperador = D.numOperador
WHERE 
    O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
    AND O.NumOperador = 900200 
    AND D.FechaSalida>='2017-03-10 00:00:00.000' AND D.FechaLlegada<='2017-03-11 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    D.NumOperador;
GO]
```

[Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RbOF.png)

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: What does "Join hours and minutes in a single field" mean. That is nonsense sounding.

Comment: where is the picture?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: An apology had not been attached, and I attached it

Comment: Looks like the query you posted would very likely produce the output in the picture. What is the issue?

Comment: I want to show hours and minutes only, I have them separately for now, now I want them to be in a single field, example 8:11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to join hrs and mns together in the result, concatenate both of them :

```
  SELECT 
D.numOperador,
  ( cast ( SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) / 60 as varchar)
 + 
cast ( SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) % 60 AS varchar )  ) as time

FROM 
trkOperadores O
INNER JOIN trfDespacho D ON O.NumOperador = D.numOperador
WHERE 
O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
AND O.NumOperador = 900200 
AND D.FechaSalida>='2017-03-10 00:00:00.000' AND D.FechaLlegada<='2017-03-11 00:00:00.000'
 GROUP BY 
D.NumOperador;
GO]
```

Comment: Thanks, you can place the : example 8:11

Comment: Thank you very much, I have achieved with your comment and just add +':'+

Comment: This answer would be even better if you specified the scale of your cast to varchar. Relying on the default size is not a great practice as the default size can vary depending on usage. Regardless this gets +1

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want something like this.

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '20170401'
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME = '20170402 00:05:00'

SELECT RIGHT( '00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @D1, @D2) /60 AS VARCHAR(2)) , 2) + ':' + RIGHT( '00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @D1, @D2) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)) , 2)

-- 24:05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    D.numOperador,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) / 60 AS [Horas] ,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) % 60 AS [Minutos]

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(CAST (D.FechaSalida AS FLOAT) - CAST (D.FechaLlegada AS FLOAT) / 86400. AS DATETIME),108) --86400 equal 1 day

    FROM 
    trkOperadores O     INNER JOIN trfDespacho D 
    ON O.NumOperador = D.numOperador
WHERE 
    O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
    AND O.NumOperador = 900200 
    AND D.FechaSalida>='2017-03-10 00:00:00.000' AND D.FechaLlegada<='2017-03-11 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    D.NumOperador;
GO
```

Comment: Why are you casting this to a float to do math? You should use DATEADD for date math.

Comment: Because internally on windows it saves as float and it is easier to work like this. If it were for different days it would be a problem.

Comment: So why not use dateadd(hour...)?